# Problem finding the right CRS for CSV file

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv, import

I got a problem regarding a CSV layer I have to use. I've imported and tried different import setting still everytime QGIS shows the points at the African coast instead of Germany. The CSV has two attributes for lat/lng but I can't tell if there might be something wrong with them.

For visualization here the screenshot of the data and import setting:
[image]

And here is the outcome after importing to the map:
[image]

Can someone give some advice on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your data is obviously in decimal degree, hence WGS 84 - EPSG 4326 is the correct CRS. In the import window change from 25832 to 4326 and you're fine.